# Having trouble understanding state-table implementation with a table-driven approach

Tags: state, table-driven

I originally was working to implement a 4-state state table in **C** using the usual switch and case methods, but recently stumbled upon the use of table-driven programming to more easily create it.

After researching it, I still find myself confused on exactly how it works.

How does table-driven programming work for state table implementation?

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions, not for vague help request about a concept.

Comment: Maybe you should also take a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/